# What is Kool-Aid Man?

Tags: comics, tv, video-games, advertisements

Besides being an anthropomorphic nearly full pitcher of cherry kool-aid, has there ever been any detailed description of how this pitcher of cherry kool-aid came to be so large, given appendages and the power to bust through walls, and yell “Oh Yeah!”

He’s got countless advertisements spanning nearly a half-century of quenching thirst, at least two video games, and about 12 issues of comics published by General Mills, Marvel Comics, and Archie Comics.

Within his lore, what is he — how did he come to be? Was he just born this way?

Comment: https://characters.fandom.com/wiki/Kool-Aid_Man

Comment: There's no help in the Marvel comicbooks. He has lots of adventures (and we meet the [Kool-Aid "Punch Bunch"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbgoO.jpg) (other anthropomorphic Kool-aid flavours) but there's no back-story explaining his genesis.

Comment: I had the Atari 2600 game, but do not recall any origin. Also that Rainbow Punch looks like **** punch.

Comment: The [Atari game manual](http://www.atarimania.com/game-atari-2600-vcs-kool-aid-man_7770.html) doesn't have any back-story

Comment: Is this on topic? If so are we opening the door to questions about the Pringle’s man? What about Mr. Peanut? How did Tony the Tiger learn to talk? Is he actually Kzinti? How long do Keebler Elves live? Not advocating one way or the other, just kinda wondering if we already decided we want to talk about product mascots.

Comment: In peanut fantasy genre. Mr. Peanut has a relatively rich fictional history that was rebooted at least once with his Baby Nut rebranding. He was grown from an odd peanut tree, and Wilkes-Barre, PA lays claim as his birthplace, some dispute that it’s Suffolk, VA where his real-world origin occurred.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Is this on topic? The Kool-Aid man would say “Oh yeah!”

Comment: Product tie-ins, particularly for toys have spawned  a number of fantasy and sci-fi franchises. No reason to ghettoize food product mascot fantasy and science fiction, the way literary snobs might ghettoize fantasy and sci-fi within literature. There are a number of competent artists who have given some of their best work to design food advertising elements, including art and prose.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - His persistent enemies were the Thirsties, aliens who came from the sun. Also he traveled in space and through time (in the comics)

Comment: @SillybutTrue: The difference between the Kool-Aid Man (whose primary purpose is to sell Kool-Aid) and, say, the Transformers (whose primary purpose is to sell toys), is that the latter actually has a plot. To the best of my understanding, the Kool-Aid commercials largely don't have a plot.

Comment: Why do you think Marvel’s Kool-Aid Man comics may be worth less artistically than Marvel’s Transformers comics?

Comment: @SillybutTrue - in fairness, they're both garbage. Comparing the 1980s Transformer comics with the Kool-Aid Bunch is like comparing differing slugs and trying to decide which you'd rather eat.

Comment: Haha. Fair point. I had epiphany the other day that J. Michael Straczynski & Kathy Tyers both wrote scripts for Jayce & The Wheeled Warriors. Sometimes a crap canvas is all Michaelangelo had to paint on.

Comment: @Kevin Plot: Act 1. People are thirsty! They say they are thirsty! What are they gonna do?! Act 2: Cue Kool-Aid man to bust through a wall, like Kool-Aid™ presumably breaks down one's thirst. Act 3: Denoument, relfecting on the wisdom and/or fun of Kool-Aid Man. See also, Hawaiian Punch commercials.

Comment: @SethMMorton That’s the best thing I’ve heard today.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In 1998, *[Hate #30](https://www.comics.org/issue/305246/)* published a 4-page comic written by Alan Moore (yes, that Alan Moore) titled, "The Hasty Smear of my Smile" which provided a fictional back-story to the Kool-Aid Man. Warning: the comic itself contains references to suicide, drug abuse, and other potentially triggering topics in a not at all subtle way.

I don't have a full version of the comic, but Mark Sobel (who worked for Fantagraphics, the publisher of *Hate*) provides a review of the four-page spread [here](https://comicsforum.org/2012/09/13/alan-moores-lost-treasures-the-hasty-smear-of-my-smile-by-marc-sobel/):

> the Kool-Aid man is not only a real person living in the real world, he is acutely aware of the absurdity of his existence. He knows he’s just a pitcher of Kool-Aid with a face ‘hastily smeared’ on it, yet he has the same human desires to be loved and accepted as anyone else.

The comic presents Kool-Aid Man's young life (he was born as a pitcher without a face, but his father drew a face with the condensation on his mug). He appears as a kind of pastiche of 60's beat poets, himself writing free verse poetry alongside Ginsberg, Kesey, and even spends some time at Jonestown.

[image: Panel 1 of Peter Bagge's Hate #30 story of the Kool-Aid Man's origin story]

Comment: There is a Kool Aid Museum in Hastings, NE. I have a call out to them for more information, but I think this stands alone as a reasonable answer.

Comment: Holy wow... I think I actually have that issue of *Hate.*

Comment: @Lexible If you do, please feel free to edit in some panels!

Comment: I have tried calling the Kool Aid Museum for an office ill answer several times. Each time they direct me to the marketing department, which doesn't return my call. Sorry!

Comment: There you go, indigochild. :)

Answer (score -1):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kool-Aid_Man):

> Marvin Potts, an art director for a New York advertising agency, was hired by General Foods to create an image that would accompany the slogan "A 5-cent package makes two quarts." Inspired by watching his young son draw smiley faces on a frosted window, Potts created the Pitcher Man, a glass pitcher with a wide smile emblazoned on its side and filled with Kool-Aid.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kool-Aid_Man

The Kool-Aid Man was born in 1974.

But then there is an [another article](https://history.nebraska.gov/publications/kool-aid):

> Kool-Aid, the popular powdered drink mix, was developed by Edwin Perkins (1889-1961) in Hastings, Nebraska. As a boy working in his family's general store in Hendley, Perkins became interested in a new powdered dessert mix named Jell-O and persuaded his father to carry it in the store.https://history.nebraska.gov/publications/kool-aid

Comment: This question seems to be enquiring about the character's _in-universe_ origin, rather than the real world backdrop to his conception.

Comment: Also, I see that the bottom half of your answer is mostly a quote from a page you linked to. Is the top half mostly a quote as well? If so, which other page did it come from?

Comment: @Eaglepup thank you, but LogicDictates is right: I’m interested in the character’s fiction origin.

Comment: Okay sorry but at least I tried

Comment: When you click another article, it will take you to a Nebraska history.

Comment: You are free to edit the question if you've something that fits. (If it gets deleted in the meantime, then you can flag a moderator to get it reopened.)